# Django: Where to store a main object and reference it from views.py + run repeating code?

Tags: python, django

I am building an app with Django to automate a reservation which I need to make every day. Django is used to provide a web interface to monitor and control this.

However, I cannot figure out where to put my code within the Django files. Before trying Django I just had a `while True` loop that made the reservation as soon as a condition was true. To do this in Django, I need to create a main object on startup and reference this from different views in the views.py file. And I need to run some kind of schedule that checks the condition if the reservation is to be made. All of this in parallel to the actual website code.

Using `celery` seems complicated and overkill for this. Is there a main Django object that is created on startup and can be accessed from other files (such as views.py)? Then I could create a parent class of this class that holds my main code and allows for starting and managing parallel jobs.

E.g., I looked at `AppConfig`, but don't know how to reference this object from other files...

```
class ReservationAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'reservation_app'
    driver = None

    def ready(self):
        # python manage.py runserver runs the ready method twice — once in each of two processes —
        # but we only want to run it once.
        if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) != 'true':
            self.driver = Safari()
            self.driver.get(LIB_ADRESS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the next approach:

You create [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management) with your `while True:` script.

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        while True:
            ... # your previous script + storing data into DB via Django models
```

This script changes state in database. So after each cycle it saves or updates some [Django models])https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/).

Django View get these models from DB and displays data on web UI.

It seems more stable, than directly accessing script's object from web threads (you risk to trap into threading-related errors).